# How to append data in the next <li>

Tags: jquery, html

i want to append data on the closest li on click...I tried next,parent,closest,find and nothing.

Here is my jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/kT3Rb/47/

My jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.btnMoreInfo', function(){
       $(this).closest(".test").next('.infoCatcher').append('<div class="moreInfo info">More Content..' + '</div>');
   });
});
```

Is not working. may i know why and how do i fix it? thanks

Comment: The closest li will be the parent of the button ... did you mean the closest li with class test ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kT3Rb/49/

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. You just want to get loads of more info's like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kT3Rb/48/) fiddle?

Comment: thanks @DaniP!...put this like an answer to valid it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `closest()` you traverse just up the three DOM, since `.test` is a sibling of the parent for your button you don't find anything.

You need something like:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.infoCatcher').append('<div class="moreInfo info">More Content..' + '</div>');
```

That will be:

- `$(this)` the actual button
- `.parent()` up to the li parent
- `.next()` target the next li which on your markup is the .test
- `.find('.infoCatcher')` and on the div infoCatcher **append**

#### [FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/kT3Rb/49/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is pure Javascript example of how you can target your closest `li`:
http://jsfiddle.net/kT3Rb/54/

And the snippet:

```js
var closestLi = document.body.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
var content = document.createTextNode('Your content here');
closestLi.appendChild(content);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>    
    </li>
    <li class="test">
         <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
   <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>    
    </li>
    <li class="test">
         <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
       <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>    
    </li>
    <li class="test">
         <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
       <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>    
    </li>
    <li class="test">
         <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using `children` and `closest` methods.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btnMoreInfo', function(){
      $(this).closest("li").next().children('.infoCatcher').append('<div class="moreInfo info">More Content..' + '</div>');
    });
});
```